# How to change UINavigationBar barTintColor when user scrolls

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the `UINavigationBar.barTintColor` from `UIColor.clearColor()` to `whiteColor()` for when the user scrolls, but also changes back to clear when the user scrolls back to the top of the view.

This is what I have been trying;

**ViewDidLoad**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

**scrollViewDidScroll**

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

However this does not work, does anybody know how I can accomplish the effect I am after ?

Comment: I am not really sure why this question was closed? The justification of "unclear what you're asking" doesn't seem reasonable here. It's pretty clear what the OP is asking. @BradLarson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    }
```